# Address the persistent sound noise issue in my car after an accident

Tags: noise, car, accident, insurance

My car was met with an accident, the doors on left side was slammed and had to be replaced. Since then I am experiencing sound noise coming from left side (not experiencing actual wind but hear window noise). I know my car well and this sound was not there before accident. I have explained this issue to Collision company (company which repaired my car) and I have been to their workshop 6-7 times. Each time they claim they have fixed the issue but nothing is helping. Insurance is saying you have to work with these guys only. how do I deal with this situation? My work schedule does not allow me to drop and pick up my vehicle. I also want to measure wind noise level inside my car. Is there any tool available to measure sound inside car ?

Shall I look for legal help ? The insurance also denied me depreciation claim saying your car is more then 7 year old .

Comment: First you say it is not wind, and then you want to measure wind noise. It might be an ill-fitting door. If you want legal help challenging your insurance company you might ask this on [SE Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What @WeatherVane stated.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I meant, If I roll my hands over door, I do not feel any wind. But I do hear sound. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It did make sense to me. There is probably just enough air squeaking through an ill-fitting crack to make the sound of wind. That doesn't mean you will fell it with your hand. You won't feel any wind when stationary. It is going at speed that creates a pressure differential between inside and outside of the car, to force air through the crack.

Comment: Depending on whether it's your insurance or the other person's insurance you might have different options. I'd suggest asking that question on the personal finance or law stackexchange.